# Can't get correct col_widths when I supply a list of tags to layout_columns (r shiny bslib)

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I'm generating a list of cards based on user input. When I supply this list of cards to `layout_columns()` it thinks it's one element and doesn't adjust the layout of the cards correctly. Specifically, it applies the width but only places one card per row. I also tried to supply `do.call(tagList, list_of_cards)` to `layout_columns()` but still same problem. See example in screenshot below when I add `col_widths = rep(6, list_of_cards)` I get the error `Warning: Truncating number of widths at 'md' breakpoint to match number of elements. • widths: 3 • elements: 1`. Repro code below.

[image: 2024-02-01 12_06_27-~_GitHub_budget_burn_rate - Shiny]

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(bslib)
library(thematic)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- page_sidebar(
  
  
  # Set the CSS theme
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "lumen",
                   version = 5
  ),
  

  
  # Add sidebar elements
  sidebar = sidebar(
    class = "bg-secondary",
    uiOutput("sidebar_content")
  ),
  
  uiOutput("main_content")
  
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  # side bar
  output$sidebar_content <- renderUI({
    list(
      selectInput("categories",
                  "Select categories",
                  choices = c("test1", "test2", "test3"),
                  selected = c("test1", "test2", "test3"),
                  multiple  = TRUE),
      selectInput("fy",
                  "Select FY",
                  choices = c(2023, 2024, 2025),
                  selected = 2024,
                  multiple  = FALSE)
    )
  })
  
  
  # # categories reactive
  # get selected categories
  categories <- reactive({ input$categories })
  fy <- reactive({ input$fy })
  
  
  # main contents
  output$main_content <- renderUI({
    
    req(categories())
    req(fy())
    
    # Create a list to store the card elements
    cats = categories()
    fy_selected = fy()
    cardList <- map(1:length(cats), function(i) {
      card(card_header(cats[i], class = "h6 text-success"), "sample")
    })
    
    # Return the list of card elements within layout_columns
    layout_columns(col_widths = rep(6, length(cats)),
                  do.call(tagList, cardList))
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Session Info

```
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.utf8
 ctype    English_United States.utf8
 tz       America/New_York
 date     2024-02-01
 rstudio  2023.12.0+369 Ocean Storm (desktop)
 pandoc   NA
─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
! package     * version date (UTC) lib source
P bit           4.0.5   2022-11-15 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P bit64         4.0.5   2020-08-30 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P bsicons     * 0.1.2   2023-11-04 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P bslib       * 0.6.1   2023-11-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P cachem        1.0.8   2023-05-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P cli           3.6.1   2023-03-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P colorspace    2.1-0   2023-01-23 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P crayon        1.5.2   2022-09-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P curl          5.2.0   2023-12-08 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P devtools      2.4.5   2022-10-11 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P digest        0.6.33  2023-07-07 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P dplyr       * 1.1.4   2023-11-17 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P fansi         1.0.6   2023-12-08 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P farver        2.1.1   2022-07-06 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P forcats     * 1.0.0   2023-01-29 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P fs            1.6.3   2023-07-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P ggiraph     * 0.8.8   2023-12-09 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P ggplot2     * 3.4.4   2023-10-12 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P glue        * 1.6.2   2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P gsheet      * 0.4.5   2020-04-07 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P gtable        0.3.4   2023-08-21 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P hms           1.1.3   2023-03-21 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P htmltools     0.5.7   2023-11-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P htmlwidgets   1.6.4   2023-12-06 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P httpuv        1.6.13  2023-12-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P jquerylib     0.1.4   2021-04-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P jsonlite      1.8.8   2023-12-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P knitr         1.45    2023-10-30 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P later         1.3.2   2023-12-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P lubridate   * 1.9.3   2023-09-27 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
P miniUI        0.1.1.1 2018-05-18 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P pillar        1.9.0   2023-03-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P pkgbuild      1.4.3   2023-12-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P pkgload       1.3.4   2024-01-16 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P profvis       0.3.8   2023-05-02 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P promises      1.2.1   2023-08-10 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P purrr       * 1.0.2   2023-08-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P Rcpp          1.0.11  2023-07-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P readr       * 2.1.5   2024-01-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P remotes       2.4.2.1 2023-07-18 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
renv          1.0.3   2023-09-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P rlang         1.1.2   2023-11-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P rstudioapi    0.15.0  2023-07-07 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P sass          0.4.8   2023-12-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P scales      * 1.3.0   2023-11-28 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P shiny       * 1.8.0   2023-11-17 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P stringi       1.8.3   2023-12-11 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P stringr     * 1.5.1   2023-11-14 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P systemfonts   1.0.5   2023-10-09 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P thematic    * 0.1.4   2023-11-04 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P tibble      * 3.2.1   2023-03-20 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P tidyr       * 1.3.1   2024-01-24 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P tidyverse   * 2.0.0   2023-02-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P timechange    0.3.0   2024-01-18 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P tzdb          0.4.0   2023-05-12 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P urlchecker    1.0.1   2021-11-30 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P usethis       2.2.2   2023-07-06 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P utf8          1.2.4   2023-10-22 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P uuid          1.2-0   2024-01-14 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P vctrs         0.6.5   2023-12-01 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P vroom         1.6.5   2023-12-05 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P withr         2.5.2   2023-10-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P xfun          0.41    2023-11-01 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
P xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
P yaml          2.3.8   2023-12-11 [?] RSPM (R 4.3.0)
[1] C:/Users/oliver/Documents/GitHub/budget_burn_rate/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32
[2] C:/Users/oliver/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1e360f03
P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
```

Comment: You may want to consider `layout_column_wrap` as it automatically adjusts according to the number of cards present, rather than calculating how many columns you want depending on the number of cards the user picks.

Comment: I figured out the problem, but I can't find the solution. When `layout_columns` builds the html, it wraps the `do.call(tagList, cardList))` in a `div` as if it was the first element in the grid. If you pass `cardList[1], cardList[2]...` you'll see the cards as expected. I can't find a solution though.

Comment: I see you found the solution in bslib's git hub. Just posting here for others: use `!!!cardList` to spread the elements.

Answer (score 0):

@gadenbuie answered on the [bslib github](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/975):

use `!!!cardList` instead of `do.call(tagList, cardList)`